# Easy RTC SQL Connection

Tags: javascript, easyrtc

I'm developing new project using Easy RTC. I'm not good at javascript and need little help about sql connections. All Easy RTC pages are .js and framework use Node JS. Designed new login page for my project but i cant connect and authenticate user. I need to connect DB and compare values. 
Do you guys have any suggestion?

Best Regards,

Answer (score -1):

```
 var connection = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection") ;

var connectionstring="Data Source=;Initial Catalog=;User ID=;Password=;Provider=SQLOLEDB";

connection.Open(connectionstring);
var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");

rs.Open("SELECT * FROM table", connection);
rs.MoveFirst
while(!rs.eof)
{
document.write(rs.fields(1));
rs.movenext;
}

rs.close;
connection.close;
```